# Mastermind algorithm with long code

Tags: java, knuth

I currently implementing [knuths mastermind algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)#Five-guess_algorithm)
But I want to create a mastermind program, where the length of the code goes up to 15. And the amount of different colors is also 15.

So I have a problem with the Seed S, mentioned in the algorithm above. When I want to create a Seed S with all possibilities the Seed would have 15^15 entries. This is 4,378938904×10¹⁷. That´s too much to handle.

Anyone got another idea how to implement knuth's algorithm with 15^15 possibilities?

Comment: Isn't this algorithm going to have this problem no matter how it is implemented?  Sounds like you need a different algorithm.

Comment: This game is great!

Comment: Why do  you need a seed at all?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a seed at all.  A seed is used for testing when you want to generate the same "random" sequence.  This generates all the combos under the sun where 1-15 are the different colors.

```
    Random rnd=new Random();
    for (int i=1; i<=15; i++) {
        System.out.print((rnd.nextInt(14)+1)+" ");
    }

}
```

Comment: And the sequence won't repeat until he got through all the possibilities?

Comment: No, if you ran that code a ton of times, eventually there will be a repeat.  I think I see what you're trying to do.  You want to generate every single combo possible, test it, and eventually this will lead you to the correct combo.  A seed isn't how you will achieve this.